# Avoiding and removing duplicates in bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We have started using bigquery for event logging from our games.

We collect events from appengine nodes and enques them in chunks now and then which are placed in a task queue.

A backend is then processing this queue and uploads events to bigquery.

Today we store ca 60 million daily events from one of our games and 6 million from another.

We have also made cron jobs to process these events to gather various gaming KPI's. (I.e. second day retention, active users, etc etc)

Everything has gone quite smooth but we do now face a tricky problem !

======== Question 1 ===============================================

Due to some reason the deletion of the queue tasks fails now and then. Not very often but it happens and often in bursts.

TransientFailureException is probably the cause ... I say probable since we are deleting process events in batch mode. I.e. ...

```
List<Boolean> Queue.deleteTask(List<TashHandle> taskstoDelete)
```

... so we actually don't know why we failed to delete a task.

We have today added retry code that will try to delete those failed deletions again.

**Is there a best practice to deal with this kind of problem?**

========= Question 2 =======================================================

Duplicate detection

The following SQL succeds to find duplicates for or smaller game but exceeds resources for
the bigger one.

```
SELECT DATE(ts) date, SUM(duplicates) - COUNT(duplicates) as duplicates
FROM (
  SELECT ts, eventId, userId, count(*) duplicates
  FROM [analytics_davincigameserver.events_app1_v2_201308]
  GROUP EACH BY ts, eventId, userId
  HAVING duplicates > 1
)
GROUP EACH BY date
```

**Is there a way to detect duplicates even for our bigger game?** 
I.e. a query that bigquery will be able to mangle our 60 million daily rows and locate duplicates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of deleting the task can you somehow mark it (through a datastore temp object for example) so that when the task runs it knows to do nothing?

Comment: for question 2: why do you need to ORDER BY?

Comment: (it might be easier to follow up and answer if you use 3 separate stackoverflow questions, for each one of your 3 questions)

Comment: FH: I removed the ORDER BY but still get "Error: Resources exceeded during query execution."

Answer (score 1):

For question #2 (I'd prefer they were separate questions, to skip this step and opportunity of confusion):

Resources are exhausted on the inner query, or the outer query?

Does this work?

```
SELECT ts, eventId, userId, count(*) duplicates
FROM [analytics_davincigameserver.events_app1_v2_201308]
GROUP EACH BY ts, eventId, userId
HAVING duplicates > 1
```

What about reducing the cardinality? I'm guessing as you are grouping by timestamp, there might be too many different buckets to group by. Does this work better?

```
SELECT ts, eventId, userId, count(*) duplicates
FROM [analytics_davincigameserver.events_app1_v2_201308]
WHERE ABS(HASH(ts) % 10) = 1
GROUP EACH BY ts, eventId, userId
HAVING duplicates > 1
```

Comment: So cardinality is too high. For further optimizations, you might need to find your sweetspot. Is it %10? Or it might make more sense to partition by time period. Week maybe? Then you don't need to go over the same results.